# How exactly were all the round constants for SHA-3 generated?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation, sha-3, lfsr

I can't seem to obtain the exact algorithm that would generate all the round constants for SHA-3.

The description can be found here:

[crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6444](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6444/why-are-the-constants-so-simple-in-keccak).

These values can be found at [github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/blob/master/src/sha_dev.js#L1450](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/blob/master/src/sha_dev.js#L1450):

```
rc_sha3 = [
        new Int_64(0x00000000, 0x00000001), 
        new Int_64(0x00000000, 0x00008082),
        ...,
        new Int_64(0x00000000, 0x80000001), 
        new Int_64(0x80000000, 0x80008008)
];
```

or at [github.com/emn178/js-sha3/blob/master/src/sha3.js#L24](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3/blob/master/src/sha3.js#L24) (in another form):

```
var RC = [1, 0, 32898, 0, 32906, 2147483648, 
...,
32896, 2147483648, 2147483649, 0, 2147516424, 2147483648];
```

I visited [keccak.noekeon.org](http://keccak.noekeon.org/) to read the Keccak reference. I have read all files from the downloadable "Files for the Keccak reference". But I still cannot understand where all those constants come from. I see them in the precomputed form, but where is the description of the actual algorithm that was used to generate them?

For example, consider the following sources:

[android.googlesource.com/.../bouncycastle/crypto/digests/KeccakDigest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bouncycastle/+/upstream-master/bcprov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/KeccakDigest.java);

[read.pudn.com/.../KeccakPermutationReference.c__.htm](http://read.pudn.com/downloads148/sourcecode/crypt/640315/KeccakReferenceAndOptimized/Sources/KeccakPermutationReference.c__.htm);

[www.grepcode.com/file/.../bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA3Digest.java](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.51/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA3Digest.java).

I tried to convert the seemingly relevant code from the above sources to JS:

```
function l(a, b) { this.x = a; this.y = b; };

function l_left(c, d)
{
    var r;
    if (32 >= d)
    {
        r = new l(
                (c.x << d) | ((c.y >>> (32 - d))),
                c.y << d
            );
    }
    else
    {
        r = new l(
                c.y << (d - 32),
                0
            );
    }
    return r;
};

function _xor(a, b)
{
    return new l(
        a.x ^ b.x,
        a.y ^ b.y
    );
}

var keccakRoundConstants = [];

function LFSR86540(LFSR)
{
    if ((LFSR & 0x80) != 0)
    {
        LFSR = ((LFSR << 1) ^ 0x71);
    }
    else
    {
        LFSR <<= 1;
    }
    return ( LFSR & 0x01) != 0;
}

function keccakInitializeRoundConstants()
{
    var L = new l(0,1);
    var LFSRstate = 0x01;
    var i, j, bitPosition;
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        keccakRoundConstants[i] = new l(0,0);
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            bitPosition = (1 << j) - 1;
            if (LFSR86540(LFSRstate))
            { 
                keccakRoundConstants[i] = _xor(keccakRoundConstants[i], (l_left(L, bitPosition) ));
            }
        }
    }
    return keccakRoundConstants;
};

keccakInitializeRoundConstants();    
console.log(keccakRoundConstants);
```

but it obviously does not generate anything (all values are set to zeroes).
Can anyone provide a readable pseudocode or Javascript version of how those constants were generated?

Comment: For one: you’re porting from something that uses 64-bit integers, but JavaScript doesn’t have those (it has 53-bit integers, and only does 32-bit bitwise operations).

Comment: @Ryan: Of course, but I already took this into account (see `Int_64` in [sha_dev.js#L35](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/blob/master/src/sha_dev.js#L35) and `l` function in my code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the shift operator `a << b` means `a << (b & 31)` for real in Java and JavaScript. Thus the original `.leftShift` is flawed. I took @Ryan-s code and fixed it:

```js
'use strict';

function hex32(n) {
    var s = (n >>> 0).toString(16);
    return "0x" + "0".repeat(8 - s.length) + s;
}

function Int64(hi, lo) {
    this.hi = hi;
    this.lo = lo;
}

Int64.of = function(hi, lo) {
  return new Int64(hi, lo);
};

Int64.prototype.shiftLeft = function (d) {
  var hi = this.hi, lo = this.lo;
  if (d < 32) {
    if (d <= 0) return this;
    return Int64.of((hi << d) | (lo >>> (32 - d)), lo << d);
  }
  if (d < 64) {
    if (d <= 32) return Int64.of(lo, 0);
    return Int64.of(lo << (d - 32), 0);
  }
  return Int64.of(0, 0);
};

Int64.prototype.xor = function (b) {
    return new Int64(
        this.hi ^ b.hi,
        this.lo ^ b.lo
    );
};

Int64.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Int64(" + hex32(this.hi) + ", " + hex32(this.lo) + ")";
};

function LFSR86540(LFSR) {
    return (LFSR & 0x80) != 0 ?
        ((LFSR << 1) & 0xff) ^ 0x71 :
        ((LFSR << 1) & 0xff);
}

function keccakInitializeRoundConstants() {
    var keccakRoundConstants = [];
    var L = new Int64(0, 1);
    var LFSRstate = 0x01;
    for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        keccakRoundConstants[i] = new Int64(0, 0);
        for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            var bitPosition = (1 << j) - 1;
            if (LFSRstate & 1) {
                keccakRoundConstants[i] = keccakRoundConstants[i].xor(L.shiftLeft(bitPosition));
            }
            LFSRstate = LFSR86540(LFSRstate);
        }
    }
    return keccakRoundConstants;
};

keccakInitializeRoundConstants().forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(String(k));
});
```

Comment: Can I replace `if (d < 64) { if (d <= 32) ... }` with `if (d < 64) { if (d === 32) ... }` in `shiftLeft`? I don't understand why "**less than** or equal" is needed here...

Comment: You can use `===`. I had a binary search in my mind thats why every comparison became a `<` or `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `LFSR` is a `byte[]` in the Java version is to allow `LFSR86540` to modify it. You can make the function return the new value instead:

```
function LFSR86540(LFSR) {
    return LFSR & 0x80 ?
        (LFSR << 1) ^ 0x71 :
        LFSR << 1;
}
```

and modify `keccakInitializeRoundConstants` accordingly:

```
LFSRstate = LFSR86540(LFSRstate);
if (LFSRstate & 1) {
    keccakRoundConstants[i] = x(keccakRoundConstants[i], l_left(L, bitPosition));
}
```

and fix `l_left`:

```
- c.y << n
+ c.y << d
```

and fix the mistake from `LFSR86540` to read the least significant bit *before* updating:

```
if (LFSRstate & 1) {
    keccakRoundConstants[i] = x(keccakRoundConstants[i], l_left(L, bitPosition));
}
LFSRstate = LFSR86540(LFSRstate);
```

Voilà: matching constants.

```js
'use strict';

function hex32(n) {
    var s = (n >>> 0).toString(16);
    return "0x" + "0".repeat(8 - s.length) + s;
}

function Int64(a, b) {
    this.x = a;
    this.y = b;
}

Int64.prototype.shiftLeft = function (d) {
    return d <= 32 ?
        new Int64(
            (this.x << d) | (this.y >>> (32 - d)),
            this.y << d
        ) :
        new Int64(
            this.y << (d - 32),
            0
        );
};

Int64.prototype.xor = function (b) {
    return new Int64(
        this.x ^ b.x,
        this.y ^ b.y
    );
};

Int64.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Int64(" + hex32(this.x) + ", " + hex32(this.y) + ")";
};

function LFSR86540(LFSR) {
    return (LFSR & 0x80) != 0 ?
        (LFSR << 1) ^ 0x71 :
        LFSR << 1;
}

function keccakInitializeRoundConstants() {
    var keccakRoundConstants = [];
    var L = new Int64(0, 1);
    var LFSRstate = 0x01;
    for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        keccakRoundConstants[i] = new Int64(0, 0);
        for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            var bitPosition = (1 << j) - 1;
            if (LFSRstate & 1) {
                keccakRoundConstants[i] = keccakRoundConstants[i].xor(L.shiftLeft(bitPosition));
            }
            LFSRstate = LFSR86540(LFSRstate);
        }
    }
    return keccakRoundConstants;
};

keccakInitializeRoundConstants().forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(String(k));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but the output of the current code in this answer is slightly different from the original. For example, the first-round original constant is `Int_64(0x00000000, 0x00000001)`, but the current code in the answer outputs `Int64(0x00000001, 0x00000001)`; the fifth-round original constant is `Int_64(0x00000000, 0x0000808B)`, but the current code in the answer outputs `Int64(0x00000001, 0x0000808b)`...